# How to disable context menu form OpenFileDialog,CommonOpenFileDialog.Or how to disable delete menu from OpenFileDialog in c#

Tags: c#

```
CommonOpenFileDialog dialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog();
RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\New", true);

//Set it to blank.
key.SetValue("", "");
dialog.IsFolderPicker = true;

if (dialog.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
```

Comment: Please explain with more details what you are trying to do and, if possible, explain why. Two reasons: 1. Your question will become clearer and more people will be able and willing to respond. 2. To show some effort. Right now it feels like you've pasted a piece of code and gave it a title. Cheers 

Comment: You might want to read [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-clean-up-your-messy-windows-context-menu/). Assuming you are perfectly understand what you are trying to do. If not, don't abuse the Registry.

Comment: There is just no point in trying to cripple the dialog, the user will simply use Explorer to accomplish the same thing.  Prevent that as well merely requires configuring normal Windows access rights.

Answer (score 0):

CommonOpenFileDialog doesn't support that operation.

You can use a custom class to do that

Check this article:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19566/Extend-OpenFileDialog-and-SaveFileDialog-the-Easy